# How to access the return value of a lambda in a another cloudformation resource?

Tags: aws-lambda, mapping, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, clientid

```
  GetClientId:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaESCognitoRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
          var response = require('cfn-response');
          var responseData = {};
          exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
            var params = {
              UserPoolId: event.ResourceProperties.UserPoolId
            };
            await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUserPoolClients(params, function(err, data) {
              if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
              else {
                console.log(data); // successful response 
                responseData = {'ClientId': data.UserPoolClients[0].ClientId};
              }
            }).promise();
            response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData);
            return;
            }
      Runtime: nodejs8.10 

   CallGetClientId:
     Type: 'Custom::CallGetClientId'
     Version: 1.0
     Properties:
       ServiceToken: !GetAtt GetClientId.Arn
       UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool

  IdentityPoolRoleMapping:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment"
    Properties:
      IdentityPoolId: !Ref CognitoIdentityPool
      Roles:
        authenticated: !GetAtt AuthenticatedRole.Arn
        unauthenticated: !GetAtt UnauthenticatedRole.Arn
      RoleMappings:
        "cognito-identity-provider":
          IdentityProvider: !Join ['', [ !GetAtt CognitoUserPool.ProviderName, ':', !GetAtt CallGetClientId.ClientId ]] #Need to get the ClientID here
          AmbiguousRoleResolution: Deny
          Type: Rules
          RulesConfiguration:
            Rules:
              - Claim: "custom:groups"
                MatchType: "Contains"
                RoleARN: !GetAtt AuthenticatedRole.Arn
                Value: "user"
              - Claim: "custom:groups"
                MatchType: "Contains"
                RoleARN: !GetAtt AuthenticatedAdminRole.Arn
                Value: "admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to resolve the issue.

One - use the `cfnresponse.send(...responseData)` parameter. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule.html#w2ab1c17c25c14b9c11

My example:

```
cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData, responseData['ClientSecret'])
```

Once you returned data from Lambda, you can refer to it in CFN template with !GetAtt:

```
Value: !GetAtt HapiUserPoolClientPostProc.ClientSecret
```

Two - I use custom resources as a components "post-processor", i.e. create the resources, and update their parameters with a custom resource after. This order will be guaranteed by custom resource lambda input parameters (dependency).

My example was to feed in Cognito AppClient callback URLs from my ElasticBeanstalk WebApp. So I create both the UserPool AppClient and the EB webapp, then a post-processor custom resource lambda takes the URL from EB and updates the CallbackURL in Cognito.

Hope this helps.